# Safari Javascript Console Autoscrolling

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, console

Is it possible to make the javascript console in Safari 6 automatically scroll down to show the most recent log? Currently, I have to manually scroll down every time I log something.

Comment: This should be in superUser I believe

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. Questions regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers" are specifically on-topic. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic The Javascript debugging console in a browser is not just commonly used by programmers - it is of virtually no interest to anyone who is not a programmer.

Comment: totally not off topic derp

Comment: I would have needed that answer as well, and it's not off topic..!

Comment: 5 yeas later I have the same problem for this "off-topic" question...

Comment: 6 years latter, same problem. Can someone just answer?